# Does the /dev/null file actually have a fixed size?

Tags: filesystem, files

I have just found out that `/dev/null` is a file and not a directory.

I'm just wondering if it has an actual file size.

Answer (score 35):

`/dev/null` is not really a file. It's a **character device**!

```
$ ls -l /dev/null
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Apr 10 09:53 /dev/null
```

The first letter `c` of the permissions string (`crw-rw-rw-`) indicates this. For regular files, it would be a `-` instead.

So in easy words: `/dev/null` is not a file but a virtual device mapped to this path in the file system, which has the only purpose to swallow and vanish data - like a black hole.
It can also be used as input though, then it acts like an empty file (size 0) and immediately returns an EOF (End Of File).

Therefore you can not really say that `/dev/null` has a specific file size, as it's not a regular file on any storage medium.

Comment: Input? What does it supply an endless list of NUL characters?

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski I don't know exactly and I never used it like this, so I can just give you this link to a [question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19955475/4464570) where it's explained.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski, no - it behaves like a zero-sized file on input, so that the first read from it reports that the file is at EOF.

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski look at /dev/zero for that.

Answer (score 16):

`/dev/null` is a special kind of file called "[device file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file)".

Device files act as a interface to some kernel functions. They just occupy the space that is needed for a directory entry ("[inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)") but don't have any real content and don't have an actual file size.

Other device files are e.g. `/dev/sda` (generally a HDD or SSD), `/dev/zero` (a file that generates zero's when read), or `/dev/random` (a file that generates random data when read). Actually about all files in `/dev/` are either device files or links pointing to device files.

Comment: While I find most of this answer correct (+1), I think that it's a little misleading to say that they occupy the size of an inode entry. They either don't occupy any space, if referring to disk space, or they take more, if referring to their whole implementation as character devices.

Comment: Just like any other file a device file needs an inode that stores the  owner, permissions, major/minor number  and other metadata. It depends on the file system how and where this inodes are stored  (you can use `mknod` to create device files anywhere you want). For virtual file systems like `/dev/` the inode doesn't occupy disc space but some memory.

Comment: Exactly. I think I didn't express myself well, so let me rephrase. Perhaps what I'm pointing out it's a little picky, so forgive me for that. What I meant is that if you state that each character device occupies some space in memory due to its inode entry, perhaps you want to point out that functions to be called upon read/write on such device, which are loaded along with them, do so also.

Comment: Is it really correct to say a file occupies the space occupied by its inode table entry? I don't think this is usually included in what people--and software people have written--mean when they talk about file size. In particular, [asking `ls` and `du` to report the size of a character special device like `/dev/null` or `/dev/random` yields 0](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10796024/).

Comment: Sorry, but I downvoted this answer, because unless someone prove me wrong on what I've said (which I might be), I still think that it's not correct to state that a character device occupies the space of an inode entry.

Comment: I don't think here is a good place for such a discussion., and I don't think this point is actually important for the answer. If you think it's important feel free to edit the answer and remove the thing about the inode.

Comment: @kos The statement that a character device occupies the space of an inode entry is correct, but slightly incomplete: there's also the space occupied by the directory entry (the part that maps the name of the file in the directory to the inode). The “implementation as character devices” is not something that takes disk space. The inode and the directory entry do occupy disk space if the device is on a disk filesystem — which is not the case for `/dev` in Ubuntu (and most Linux distributions) but that's another story.

Comment: @Gilles Sorry but either I don't understand what it's being pointed out to me or I can't convey well what I'm trying to point out.  *In this particular case*, since we are not talking about disk space, it's slightly incorrect to say that a character device occupies the size of an inode entry *overall*, because what is actually loaded in memory upon the device creation is more than just a `struct`, the rest of the implementation (for example global / local variables and what is used within read / write function definitions) takes space also.

Comment: @kos You're confusing disk space with memory usage here, and you're also confusing the directory entry with the driver code that implements it. Florian's answer contains no incorrect or misleading statement.

Comment: Not to be rude, but really, since this debate has been extended too much for comments already, I'll stop here commenting. Hopefully somebody will be able to explain within the next comment exactly (*if* that's the case, and it should be clear already that I believe it's not) *why my assertion is wrong* instead of just stating *whether OP's assertion it's true*, which is not really useful for me to understand (again, *in case* I'm wrong), nor within any discussion to prove *any* point.